# Where is the Gnome 3 Skype tray icon?

Tags: gnome, icons, skype, system-tray

I installed Skype using Flatpak and I would like to change my Skype tray icon with a monochrome one but I can't find it on disk. I changed all the `*.png` files in `/var/lib/flatpak/app/com.Skype.Client` thinking I might find out which one is the tray icon.

All the icons changed, including the dock one and the one which appears when you serach for it

[image]

but the tray icon still remains the same:

[image]

Does anyone have any idea where the tray icon is located?